# Error while converting to Date format in R

Tags: r, date

It should be an easy issue, but I got stacked with it. I have a data.frame with dates and values:

```
    class(var_data)
    [1] "tbl_df"     "tbl"        "data.frame"
    var_data
    A tibble: 42 x 2
       date                Tourists
       <dttm>                 <dbl>
     1 2006-03-01 00:00:00   55280.
     2 2006-06-01 00:00:00   84392.
     3 2006-09-01 00:00:00  132714.
```

Then I want to copy some dates and values into other data.frame:

```
    var_list_DB$var_last[ii] <- var_data[last,"Tourists"]
    var_list_DB$var_date_start[ii] <- var_data[1,"date"]
    var_list_DB$var_date_last[ii] <- var_data[last,"date"]
```

But instead of dates I got numbers:

```
    var_date_start   var_date_last  var_val_last 
    951868800        1496275200      10044.3162
```

And while trying to convert to date format, got an error:

```
    as.Date(var_data[last,"date"], format = "%m/%d/%Y")
    Error in as.Date.default(x, ...) : 
      do not know how to convert 'x' to class “Date”
```

I recently updated to 3.5.0 version, may be this is an issue.

Comment: Where is `var_list` and what is 'i1' ?  Please use `dput` to show the example

Answer (score 0):

Add `as.character` convertion before pass to date and move var_data to `data.frame` format, like this two examples using `as.Date` and `as.POSIXct`:

```
var_data<-data.frame(var_data)
as.Date(as.character(var_data[,"date"]))
[1] "2006-03-01" "2006-06-01" "2006-09-01"
as.POSIXct(as.character(var_data[,"date"]))
[1] "2006-03-01 CET"  "2006-06-01 CEST" "2006-09-01 CEST"
```

Comment: I got an error, while trying toconvert > as.Date(as.character(var_data[obs,"date"]))
Error in charToDate(x) : 
  character string is not in a standard unambiguous format
> as.character(var_data[obs,"date"])
[1] "1464739200"